# how to overwrite the functionality of all print methods using scripts in grails

Tags: java, grails, groovy

In grails we can redirect the print methods in scripts and run using the `GroovyShell` as shown below.

```
def scriptText = '''   
def s = "Groovy rocks!"     
println s      
printf 'The answer is %X', 42    
'''    
def shell = new GroovyShell()        
def script = shell.parse(scriptText)    
def stringWriter = new StringWriter()    
script.out = new PrintWriter(stringWriter)

script.run()   
assert stringWriter.toString() == 'Groovy rocks!\nThe answer is 2A'
```

but i want to make the output of print into a file and execute the default functionality of println, printf or println etc.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the output stream for the jvm.

```
System.out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(...))
```

I see you are using `script.out` which may work as well.

This should set the default output stream for any of the System.print methods you are using.